# How to move the num to the position right of the image

Tags: html, css

[image]

Tried float:right but the image will only show half...
What I want is to move **123** move to the red circle

```css
#ImgControl{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #ffd7c2;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ImgControl">
  <img  src="assets\icon\cart.png" @click="Test"/>
  <span>123</span>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to move the span inside the ImgControl div, after the image?

Comment: if you are using `position:absolute` to achieve that, maybe you should use `top: 20px;` instead of `bottom: 20px;`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan i tried that, the 123 will become below of the cart png you can check this link >>> https://ibb.co/YXmdShN

Comment: You should insert a runnable snippet of code of the menubar in your question, a screenshot is not helpful.

Comment: @DiegoD hi i tried change bottom to top 20px but nothing much change the 123 still below the image

Comment: try below answer hope its helps

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan hi, i updated code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `width` you defined, which is too small to contain all the elements side by side: remove it or change it to `fit-content` so it will adapt to the content

```css
#ImgControl{
    width: fit-content;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #ffd7c2;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ImgControl">
  <img  src="assets\icon\cart.png" @click="Test"/>
  <span>123</span>
</div>
```

Comment: cool, now its fit with image thanks

Answer (score 0):

try like below,

```css
#ImgControl{
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
background-color: #ffd7c2;
position: absolute;
top: 11px;
right: 20px;
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="ImgControl">
    <span>123</span>
    <img  src="assets\icon\cart.png" @click="Test"/>
    
</div>
```

Comment: try to add `#ImgControl *{display: inline-block;}` and remove the width in the container so that those two elements will be next to each other

Comment: i checked the code snippet but the 123 is above the image. I am looking for the answer that 123 show right side of the image

Comment: now try it, it's workign